# JavaFX Fxml Display Image

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have been endeavouring to implement a JavaFX application which includes the display of an image using fxml.

However, it is unclear to me how to successfully create the image url.

I have tried using the ampersand annotation to create a relative path and also tried an absolute path but all are rejected by the IDE.

Consequently I have created a simplified application as follows:

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Display an Image");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<FlowPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <ImageView fx:id="ivWoodland">
        <image>
            <Image fx:id="imgWoodland" url="file:///D:/TF/ImageDemo/woodland.jpg"/>

        </image>

    </ImageView
```

If anybody can inform me how to format the url it will be much appreciacted.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to load it as a resource which is bundled as part of your application, not as a file. Where is the image located, relative to the FXML file? If you use `url="@path/to/image.jpg"`, the path will be treated as relative to the FXML file. If you use `url="path/to/image.jpg"` the path will be treated as relative to the classpath.

Comment: If your code is modular I recommend the `@` approach; it'll make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you both. I had intended to state in the OP that the image file is located in the Project folder but unfortunately I omitted this. Images in this location have always worked when creating a GUI in code. Moving the image to the package has resolved the issue.